# Ghost margin coming between M3 bottom sheet and keyboard when focusing on a TextField embedded in BottomSheet

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3, android-compose-textfield

I'm trying to implement M3 ModalBottomSheet using Jetpack Compose 1.5.3. There is a editable TextField inside bottom sheet which when focused, it's not moving relative to the keyboard and rather some ghost margin is coming between the Keyboard and ModalBottomSheet.

[image: Normal Screen When BottomSheet is not opened]

[image: Ghost padding which is coming between bottom sheet and keyboard]

The implementation has following view structure

```
if(showSheet){
ModalBottomSheet(.....)
}

Scaffold(...){paddingValues ->
 Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(paddingValues)){
     .............
 }
}
```

We've tried this with M2 bottom sheet and this issue was not there.